# Find columns where week row and year row matches values given in another cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a matrix in excel where the 2 top rows are "Year" and "Week".

As you probably could imagine there is a lot of columns in this matrix as time goes by. Therefore I would like a button that simply sends the user to the column with year and week matching the 2 "search cells"

To illustrate:

[image]

What I want is just to select the column or Year-Week range that matches the criterias in cell B1 and B2.

So that it would select column C or range("C4:C5") with the criterias given in the picture.

I simply cant wrap my head around it atm, so I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered conditionsl formatting?

Comment: You mention you want to select those cells, but as you can't select different non-existing cells (or at least it's not common), wouldn't you prefer to highlight them, as indicated in the first comment from [Solar Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961700/solar-mike)?

Comment: I allready added conditional formatting to the cells. But as time goes and years are getting added with 52 weeks each, there will hundreds of columns. Thats why i would like a button, that could direct you to the current week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here example:

```
Sub test()

Dim criteria1$, criteria2$
Dim cl As Range, data As Range

criteria1 = [B1].Value
criteria2 = [B2].Value

Set data = [B4:G5]

For Each cl In data
    If cl.Value = criteria1 And cl.Offset(1, 0).Value = criteria2 Then
        Range(cl, cl.Offset(1, 0)).Select
    End If
Next cl

End Sub
```

you can assign this `Sub` to button/shape/picture ...

Comment: What if there are different such cells? I believe that only the last one will be selected, isn't it?

Comment: @Dominique, there might be too much "what if" here, I'm just showing an example of how this can be achieved.

Comment: Awesome Vasily! It worde perfectly on my test sheet. Now i will try to implement it into my full dataset with the matix.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use COUNTIF first to check if the value exist and then EVALUATE to get column number and select

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim ThisColumn As Integer

'first, check that year and week exists
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A4:G4"), Range("B1"), Range("A5:G5"), Range("B2")) = 0 Then
    'not found
    MsgBox "Year and week not found", vbCritical, "ERROR"
Else
    'found, then select
    ThisColumn = Evaluate("=MATCH(B1&B2,TRANSPOSE(A4:G4)&TRANSPOSE(A5:G5),0)")
    Range(Cells(4, ThisColumn), Cells(5, ThisColumn)).Select
End If

End Sub
```

If you put a year and or a week not found, then it will raise an error:

[image]

Please, note that you'll need to adapt the ranges in case you have more values at rows 4 and 5